# Why am I getting: settings.json: parse error reading settings file?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, meteor-slingshot

I'm trying to upload to Amazon s3 using edgee:slingshot on OSX. It appears I need to create a settings.json file and put it in the root, which I did. But, I get settings.json: parse error reading settings file. What am I doing wrong? (I did not copy/paste). Any help greatly appreciated.

**settings.json**

```
{
    "key": "myAWSAccessKeyId",
    "secret": "myAWSSecretKey",
    "bucket": "mybucketname",
    "acl": "public-read",
}
```

Now getting:

```
W20170127-23:46:55.176(-8)? (STDERR) Error: Match error: Unknown key in field secret
W20170127-23:46:55.176(-8)? (STDERR)     at exports.check (packages/check.js:57:15)
W20170127-23:46:55.176(-8)? (STDERR)     at new Slingshot.Directive (packages/edgee_slingshot.js:325:3)
W20170127-23:46:55.177(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.Slingshot.createDirective (packages/edgee_slingshot.js:295:5)
W20170127-23:46:55.177(-8)? (STDERR)     at app/server/main.js:1:-17
W20170127-23:46:55.177(-8)? (STDERR)     at app/server/main.js:24:4
W20170127-23:46:55.178(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/lgulli/revume/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:295:34
W20170127-23:46:55.178(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170127-23:46:55.179(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/lgulli/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1c557gy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20170127-23:46:55.191(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/lgulli/revume/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
W20170127-23:46:55.192(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/lgulli/revume/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:344:5
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, unlike JavaScript, it is illegal for the last property in an object to end with a comma.

Try:

```
{
    "key": "myAWSAccessKeyId",
    "secret": "myAWSSecretKey",
    "bucket": "mybucketname",
    "acl": "public-read"
}
```

Comment: Yes. I see that you're right.  Now, I have a bunch of other errors (posted above). Time to start researching those. If you have any insight, please let me know and thank you!

Comment: I came back to accept your answer as it was correct and worked. The rest was on me. My up-votes aren't publicly shown but still get recorded. Thanks Richard!

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy to have helped. But it looks like you haven't up-voted or marked as the answer.